# Create thumbnail for .flv and .swf video files

Tags: flash, flv

I need to create the thumbnail of .flv and .swf video files. Searched on google and most of the links suggested about using trail version but I am not able to find any simple code based tutorial. How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so we don't repeat old ideas? **FFmpeg** is a useful tool for extracting frames as images from many video formats.

Comment: @VC.One: yea got it, i got library to do the work.